# error connect to sql database from visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I'm new in programming visual studio with c#. I want to connect my data from visual studio to mysql database. I'm using XAMPP as server, but when I try to connect, it gives the error message: "connection must be valid and open". I don't know how to fix it. I have tried some ways to fix this, and still not fix.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace scadaSql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection connectionMySql;

        bool statusServer = false;
        string server = "localhost";
        string database = "topsus_iot";
        string uid = "root";
        string pass = "";
        string conString;
        int checkCounter = 0;
        int timeCounter = 0;
        int filesCnt = 0;
        int loopProg = 0;

        public void sqlInsert(int temp, int humidity)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = connectionMySql.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (device_id, temperature, humidity) VALUE(2, @temp, @humidity)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp", temp);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@humidity", humidity);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception X)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(X.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public bool sqlClose()
        {
            try
            {
                connectionMySql.Close();
                label4.Text = "disconnected";
                label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool sqlOpen()
        {
            try
            {
                connectionMySql.Open();
                label4.Text = "Connected";
                label4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException mx)
            {
                switch (mx.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pass + ";";
            connectionMySql = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            statusServer = false;
            sqlOpen();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlInsert((int)temperature.Value, (int)humidity.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slight detour....http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Do you get an exception when opening the connection in the method sqlOpen()? Or is it setting label4.Text to connected? Also try to start the method names with an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your connection before you create the sql command.
It seems you never call your SQLOpen method so the connection is never initialized and opened and as such your insert statement fails.

I recommend creating a constructor for your class and calling the open command on it.

Also, don´t forget to call sqlClose() after you´re done running the command.

Comment: easiest way to deal with the closing is implementing IDisposable and calling the code inside a `using` block.